# Can't push to repo [GIT]: Anonymous access denied

Tags: git, github, proxy

I create a new repo using Github web, I cloned it and now I am trying to push the creation of a new file.

I am getting the following error:

```
Username for 'https://github.com': user
Password for 'https://user@github.com': 
remote: Anonymous access to user/repo.git denied.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/user/repo.git'
```

I am behind a corporate proxy so the use of ssh is not an option. I MUST solve this using https. Any idea of what is going on? I couldn't find any valid solution after spending a reasonable amount of time...

Comment: Have you configured Git to use your corporate proxy ? `git config --global http.proxy my.proxy.com:8080` for example.

Comment: Yes I did but that is not solving the problem

Comment: Looks like the username and/or password that you have provided is incorrect.

Comment: Yeap, I have also checked that the login data was correct...